# unknown mutation type: SET_STOCK

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vuejs3

im doing a stock trader app using vuex and axios for fetching data in my firebase.
this is my actions module and im exporting these to 2 vuex modules, Stocks.js and Protfolio.js as you can see on my commits.
but i always get this error [vuex] unknown mutation type: SET_STOCK

**NOTE: IM USING VUEjs 3**

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export const loadData = ({ commit }) => {
axios.get('https://stock-trader-80090-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/data.json')
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            const stocks = data.stocks;
            const funds = data.funds;
            const stockPortfolio = data.stockPortfolio;

            const portfolio = {
                stockPortfolio,
                funds
            }
            commit('SET_STOCK', stocks)
            commit('SET_PORTFOLIO', portfolio)
        }
    })
}
```

this is my stocks.js vuex module btw

```js
import stocks from '../../data/stocks'

const state = {
    stocks: []
};

const mutations = {
    'SET_STOCKS'(state, stocks) {
        state.stocks = stocks
    },
    'RND_STOCKS'(state) {
        state.stocks.forEach(stock => {
            stock.price = Math.round(stock.price * (1 + Math.random() - 0.5));
        })
    }
};

const actions = {
    buyStock: ({ commit }, order) => {
        commit('BUY_STOCK', order);
    },
    initStocks: ({ commit }) => {
        commit('SET_STOCKS', stocks)
    },
    randomizeStocks: ({ commit }) => {
        commit('RND_STOCKS');
    }
};

const getters = {
    stocks: state => {
        return state.stocks;
   }
};

export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

Comment: `SET_STOCK` vs `SET_STOCKS`. Typo

Comment: MY MAN hahaha i didnt see that hahahaha thanks man